# Using String's equals() implementation inside another equals() implementation?

Tags: java, equals

Let's say a `class Member` where member has an `Id` of type `String`. I want to know if there might be any problem with using a `String equals()` implementation inside another implementation. Would it be any better if the `field Id` was of type `Long`.

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object object){
  if(object == null) return false;
    if(! (object instanceof Member)) return false;
    Member member= (Member) object;
    if(this.Id.equals(member.Id))  //<==My concern is here
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it would be any problem? Did you face one while running it?

Comment: You should be fine as long as this.Id is never null. By convention, though, it should be "id", not "Id".

Comment: You should use `Objects.equals(Id, member.Id)`. Other than that it's fine.

Comment: @EricStein Sounds like a fully sufficient answer to me

Comment: @nosid. Provided OP is using Java 7. Anyways, that's pretty unintuitive to compare strings like that.

Comment: @nosid Why? I wouldn't compare strings like that elsewhere, why would I compare them like that here?

Comment: @RohitJain No I didn't face any problem just want to learn from experts.. @EricStein if `id` is `null` what difference would it make?

Comment: @user976095. NullPointerException.

Comment: @Cruncher: Because it works correctly with `null`. There is no need to use it, if you compare a `String` to a _string literal_. But you should use it in all other situations - not only for `String`s.

Comment: @user976095 You'll find these kind of things are often recursive. If some other class has an instance of your class as one of it's fields it would probably call your equals method to check for equality. And your equals methods in turn checks for equality of all your members by calling their equals methods. You eventually get to objects that only have primitives.

Comment: @Cruncher so if I have a possibility to use `id` as a `Long` it is preferable to consider a primitive

Comment: @user976095 I think using a `long` or `int` for `id` is preferable for more reasons than there primitiveness(is this a word? Maybe primitivosity? xD).

Comment: For the sake of readability: just ``return this.Id.equals(member.Id)`` instead of the ``if(condition) return true else return false;`` block

Comment: If `id` actually represents a number, then yes, use a number.  If not, then don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is that you may have more class members besides `id` and your `equals` implementation will say `true` even while two instances differ greatly but have the same `id`. With this in mind, make sure to have a consistent `hashCode` implementation alongside to avoid inconsistencies.

Another idea is to define custom comparators e.g.

```
static Comparator<Member> MEMBER_ID_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Member>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Member first, Member second) {
       assert(first.getId() != null);
       assert(second.getId() != null);
       return first.getId().compareTo(second.getId());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all.  From this point of view, leave `Id` as a `String`.  If it's only going to contain numbers, yes, you can use `Long` or `BigInteger` (my preference).  But this is a different animal whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object object){
  if(object == null) return false;
  if(! (object instanceof Member)) return false;
  Member member= (Member) object;
  if (this.Id == null && member.Id == null)
      return true;
  else if (this.Id != null && member.Id != null)
      return this.Id.equals(member.Id);
  else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: `this.Id == null && member.Id == null` could be rewritten as `this.Id == member.Id`